# How to pass values of a dropdown list from html to python using django

Tags: python, django

I am sure this is a simple syntax issue I am not able to resolve. I just started working in django to try to move away from tkinter for my python hobby project. List below are my views, template, and url files.

All I want for my front end GUI is to have a user select a file path, a Area, and a type of output. I plan on pass off this values to python to do some logic with.

When I hit my submit button I get this line debug output on my output page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in WebFetcher.urls, Django tried these URL patterns,
in this order:
    
[name='home']
[name='page_objects']
admin/
The current path, views, didn't match any of these.
```

My views:

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.http import *
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def page_objects(request):
    Area = request.GET["Area"]
    Output = request.GET["Output"]
    print(Area)
    print(Output)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

My template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Please Select Your Document, and the Area</h2>
    <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    <p>Then hit submit!</p>
    <p>
        <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
    </p>


    <form action="/views" method="post">
        <select name="Area">
                <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
                <option value="P10">P10</option>
                <option value="P20">P20</option>
                <option value="P30">P30</option>
                <option value="P40">P40</option>
                <option value="P50">P50</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Output">
                <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
                <option value="List">List</option>
                <option value="Address">Address</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('', views.home, name = 'page_objects')
]
```

Comment: You haven't told us _what the problem is_.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry I did forget to do that... I am getting this text from the debug when I hit my submit button....................Using the URLconf defined in WebFetcher.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='home']
[name='page_objects']
admin/
The current path, views, didn't match any of these.

Comment: The form action url is `/views`, and your urls.py file does not define any view with that url.

Comment: does this line" path('', views.home, name = 'page_objects')" not cover that?

Comment: No it does not, because that line defines an _empty_ url path, which does not match `/views`.

Comment: I changed it to " path('views', views.home, name = 'page_objects') " which is giving me another error which I think is good around the CSRF. I think I saw how to resolve this in a youtube video I watched using jinja.